# SQL Server : user-defined functions (return day of week for specified date)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have only just started with UDFs and I am having troubles with the following exercise question:

> Create a user-defined function that will for a given date return the number of the day of the week

As an example we were given the following:

```
USE [AdventureWorks]; 
GO 

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnIsWeekday 
     (@p_date [DATETIME]) 
RETURNS [BIT] AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @weekday [BIT]

    IF (SELECT DATENAME(dw, @p_date)) IN (N'Friday', N'Saturday', N'Sunday') 
    BEGIN 
        SET @weekday = 0 
    END 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @weekday = 1 
    END 

    RETURN (@weekday) 
END; 
GO
```

My question is: how do I alter this function to accommodate every day of the week as opposed to having them grouped?

Comment: Good luck if you run this code on a SQL Server instance that is **not** using the English language......

Answer (score 1):

You do not need really need a UDF for this. But since you need to write one because the exercise calls for it,

```
return (datepart(dw,@p_date))
```

is all your UDF needs to do.

Comment: Your syntax is not correct .  should be select datepart(dw,@p_date)

Comment: Nor are the semantics correct. This would return an integer between `1` and `7` that is then implicitly cast to `bit`. i.e. it would always return `1` regardless of the value of `@p_date`

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thank you, fixed.

Comment: @MartinSmith I didn't set out to rewrite the entire function. OP would have had to change the return type of the function in any case.

Comment: Ah - sorry I didn't read the Q properly. I thought this was in some way supposed to have the same semantics as the code they posted.